# Porque meus Labels não aparecem no swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Alguém pode me ajudar? é um erro bem de novato, porque meus labels não estão aparecendo no swing?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class first{

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    JLabel c = new JLabel("Seja bem-vindo!");
    f.add(c);
    JButton b = new JButton("CLICK");
    b.setBounds(130,100,100,40);

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(b);
    f.setSize(400,500);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

É uma resposta mais-ou-menos porque não domino o assunto a fim de explicar melhor o que está acontecendo, mas deve funcionar se fizer:

```
f.getContentPane().add(c);
```

Também é preciso remover a seguinte linha:

```
f.setLayout(null);
```

Procure sempre usar layouts em vez de setá-los como `null`.

Estude o código que modifiquei abaixo.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(

                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JFrame f = new JFrame();
                        JLabel c = new JLabel("Seja bem-vindo!");
                        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
                        panel.add(c);
                        JButton b = new JButton("CLICK");
                        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        panel.add(b);
                        f.setSize(400,500);
                        f.setVisible(true);
                        //f.pack(); // Experimente com pack() para ver como fica
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Note que:

- Estou chamando código de GUI de dentro do EDT (Event-Dispatch Thread) através do `invokeLater()`;
- Por ser um top-level container, o JFrame tem o content pane, que outros containers como JPanel não têm. Acredito que não é uma boa ideia mexer no content pane à toa, além de somente adicionar um container a ele (ou mais de um, talvez). Feito isso trabalha-se com o `JPanel`, definindo-se o layout a ser usado ou deixando o `FlowLayout`, que é o padrão desse container.

Comment: Pode ser meio tarde pra comentar, mas os labels nao aparecem porque ele anulou o layout da tela e não definiu as coordenadas nem as medidas deles. Se você olhar no método setBounds, verá que ele aceita receber tanto as coordenadas propriamentes ditas, quanto uma classe do awt chamada "Retangle". É ela quem definirá a área que o componente ocupará, anulando layout, ela inicia como {0,0,0,0}

Comment: @BlastoiseOpressor Ou seja, faltou `f.setBounds(...);`?

Comment: Isso, faltou definir o setbounds dos labels.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você trabalha com layout null, você tem que definir o posicionamento de todos os objetos. O seu código está ok, você só esqueceu de posicionar o label:

```
c.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
```